# Style disabled ion-select

Tags: css, angular, select, styles, ionic2

How to remove transparent style from ion-select which is disabled ?
Please help.

```
  <ion-item (click)="goToProducts()">
    <ion-label stacked>product</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="product" disabled class="disabled">
      <ion-option value="1">Product 01</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

on scss file

```
   .disabled{ ?
   }
```

Comment: I don't see any transparent on the [Select documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/)

Comment: <ion-item> is transparent  when I add disabled  on <ion-select>

Comment: You mean written in a lighter grey?

Comment: use `/deep/` selector in your wrapping component to style children components...

Answer (score 3):

I add this:

```
.select-disabled, .item-select-disabled ion-label {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

create a class example class="select" then on scss add this?

`select { --placeholder-opacity: 100% ; }`